# creating a math quiz using if else

Tags: python

Hi i'm using python to write a simple math quiz for my college class using if else statements but my code will only put out the (else) print even when the (if) conditions are met.

*Code Below*

```
import random
num1 = random.randint(1,20)
num2 = random.randint(1,20)
print(num1,'+',num2)
user_answer = input("Your answer here: ")
real_answer = num1+num2
print(real_answer, user_answer)
if user_answer == real_answer:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: user_answer is a string, real_answer is a number. You should compare values of the same type.

Comment: `if input(f"{num1}+{num2}\nYour answer here: ") == str(num1 + num2):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the types are different you have to convert input to integer first like below.

```
import random
num1 = random.randint(1,20)
num2 = random.randint(1,20)
print(num1,'+',num2)
user_answer = int(input("Your answer here: "))
real_answer = num1+num2
print(real_answer, user_answer)
if user_answer == real_answer:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using Python 3.x (and not 2.x), your problem is that `input` returns a string, not a number.  You need to explicitly convert it to one.

```
user_answer = int(input("Your answer here: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're testing a string against an int.
Try something like:

```
if int(user_answer) == real_answer:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("no")
```